# How to use MgtTeamsChannelPicker in React?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I imported all necessary libs.

```
import "@microsoft/mgt";
import "@microsoft/teams-js"
```

put tag MgtTeamsChannelPicker into my render section

```
render() {
  return (
    <MgtTeamsChannelPicker></MgtTeamsChannelPicker>    
  );
}
```

than i got an error.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to how react handles custom elements, they must be referenced differently. Alternatively you can use our wrapper here:

https://github.com/nmetulev/mgt-react

which will allow you to reference the component in the following way:

```
import { TeamsChannelPicker } from 'mgt-react';
<TeamsChannelPicker></TeamsChannelPicker>
```

*quick note: The names of the React components are in PascalCase and do not include the Mgt prefix*